# Regular expression to terminate all characters between > and <

Tags: java, regex

I have an string like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
  <m:GetStockPrice>
  <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
  </m:GetStockPrice>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i want to remove any thing including white spaces and newlines in between > and < and make this string in a single line.

how can i achieve this in java

Comment: Is it in a `String` now, or what format do you have it in? Please show us actual code, including what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well you can use `yourString.replaceAll(">[.\\s]*<", "><"))`

Edit:
Okay so you provided snippet with whitespaces only. Now try my code.

Comment: Not working. I want to eliminate all the things in between a closing tag > and the next opening tag <.for example if the string is like <abc>3</abc>   /n<def>3</def>.the o/p should be <abc></abc><def></def>

Comment: Can you show me your code how you do this? For me it is removing all whitespaces between `>` and `<`. How does my code work for you? Do this change anything?

Comment: Okay I edited my code. I thought you wanted to remove only whitespaces from your string.

Comment: this code is doing nothing for me.. String s = "<abc>3</abc>   /n<def>3</def>";
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll(">(\\s*)<", "><"));  this is my code.The o/p is <abc>3</abc>   /n<def>3</def> this itself

Comment: I think my answer is not 100% well construct. Better regexp would be `yourString.replaceAll(">[^<]*\\s*<", "><")`

Comment: what if i needed to remove any character,not only white spaces?

Comment: I think code from my latest comment removes any character and it should do the thing you asked for.